# Errors while setting loop ! While/if/else/elif?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

The Problem is fairly the less of knowledge. But heres my problem.

I tried to do a while loop for figuring out which language the customer wants to choose

I tried to set a simple "Question-Answer" Script with a while loop. Continue for Var A(varr) and break for Var B(othervarr)

Python said "continue is not properly set in loop"
or "break outside loop"

So now my question is not to give me a superb code like you did (i even wouldnt understand) my question is whats the difference between a while loop and if/else ? Would it be better to do it with if/else statements ? And how split the possibilities for customer to choose "A" (and get script for a) or choose "B" (to get script for b) ?

Thanks in advance for your time

```
varr = "german"
othervarr = "english"

print("Hello everybody. This is the first Version of 'Ismypasswordsafe' ! If you want to enter in german, type german below, if you want to continue in english, type english below")
while input() == varr:
continue;
print("Du hast dich fuer Deutsch entschieden !")
if input() == othervarr:
break;
print("Alright you choosed English")
```

Comment: You have to use indentation to declare the scope of the code.

Comment: Don't call `input()` twice, instead assign it to a variable, also indent your code and then we will talk about loops.

Comment: @Dave M, you are getting downvoted only because your code is not formatted. This is very important in Python, so please fix this so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Indent your code and you want to save the input into a variable.  Once you have the chosen language you want to print one of two things so do if A else B

```
varr = "german"
othervarr = "english"

print("Hello everybody. This is the first Version of 'Ismypasswordsafe' ! If you want to enter in german, type german below, if you want to continue in english, type english below")
lang = input()

while not (lang == "english" or lang == "german"):
  print("You must enter 'english' or 'german'")
  lang = input()

if lang == "english":
  print("Alright you choosed English")
else:
  print("Du hast dich fuer Deutsch entschieden !")
```

EDIT - Updated based on the comments to loop until one of the two languages was chosen.

While is a loop and will loop *while* the condition is true.  So in English: while lang is not english and not german loop asking for more input.

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: I think `else if` is better. And it seems OP wants to loop until input is either "German" or "English"

Comment: Thank you really much. If you now can tell me the difference between a while loop and if/else my day ends up perfectly. 
And yes in my thougths i wanted to loop until the language selection is done.

Comment: Can you see the difference now after I updated the code based on Benoit's comment?

Comment: Clearly ! Now i got it, Thanks in advance for spending your time to a beginner

Answer (score 0):

1. Always allot your input() to a variable.
2. Always indent your code.
3. As per your question, while and if/else are completely different things. The former being a loop i.e. it helps executing a particular set of operations over and again while if/else is a conditional statement i.e. ‘if’ the condition is satisfied this part is executed, ‘else’ the other one is.

You might want to read the documentation to learn more about it.

[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question you don't want to use a while loop for this because it will only run while the condition is true.

so for your code

```
while input() == varr:
```

is great if the user inputs german but will never start if the user inputs english.

You are much better off with a input that is outside any loop and then just use a if statement to check the input.

The problem with doing else after if is its not really checking the other input, its just saying if its not one it must be the other.

Please see below.

```
varr = "german"
othervarr = "english"

language = input("Hello everybody. This is the first Version of 'Ismypasswordsafe' ! If you want to enter in german, type german below, if you want to continue in english, type english below")

if language == varr:
    print("Du hast dich fuer Deutsch entschieden !")
if language == othervarr:
    print("Alright you choosed English")
```

The other thing to note of course is that indentation is very important in python and dictates the order that the code is executed.

Your original error of "continue is not properly set in loop" is because the continue is in line with while.

it should be,

```
while input() == varr:
    continue;
```

Now python knows the continue is inside the while loop.